# Showing NSAttributedString at the Center With NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsattributedstring

I have the following function to make an attributed string.

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)makeText:(NSString *)txt : (NSString *)fontname : (CGFloat)tsize :(NSColor *)textColor :(NSColor *)shadowColor :(NSSize)offset {
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = shadowColor;
    shadow.shadowOffset = offset;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10.0f;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSCenterTextAlignment;

    NSMutableAttributedString *atext = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:txt];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,txt.length);

    // alignment
    [atext addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0,[atext length])];

    ...
    ...
    return atext;
}
```

If I set this attributed string to NSTextField, the resulting attributed string will be aligned correctly.  But if I send it to NSView's subclass, the string will be left-aligned.  Is there any way by which I can display this attributed string with correct alignment?

```
// .h
@interface imageView1 : NSView {
    NSAttributedString *aStr;
}

// .m
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [aStr drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint((self.frame.size.width-aStr.size.width)/2.0f,(self.frame.size.height-aStr.size.height)/2.0f)];
}
```

Thank you for your help.  The OS version is 10.8.

Comment: Sorry about my iOS-based answer (now deleted). - In iOS we can also just use TextKit to draw; I bet you can do something similar. See this example (it's iOS but I'm betting it's almost identical in OS X), option 2: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p510attributedStringDrawing2/ch23p773attributedStringDrawing/StringDrawer.m

Comment: Also see the docs on your `drawWithRect:options:`, which is simpler (and is like the wrong answer I gave).

Comment: The point is that if you draw at a point there are no bounds to center in relation to!

Comment: Yes.  The documentation says it has unlimited width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw at a point there are no bounds in relation to which to center. You need to specify a rect. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/drawWithRect%3aoptions%3a) on `drawWithRect:options:`. Note the admonition there pointing out that to be *in* that rect your options will need to be (or include) `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`.